# Bash/Perl/Regex - regex wont work with a single line but works with full file

Tags: regex, bash, perl

The Goal: Read every line, extract information via regex, return it to the bash script

The Problem: When the whole file is a string in the perl code, it work, however if its given line by line via bash, it wont find anything.

The Bash Side:

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
RESULT=$(perl /mnt/c/LINUX_STUFF/regex.pl $line)
echo $RESULT
done < example.config
```

The Perl Side:

```
use strict;
my $str = $ARGV[0];
my $regex = qr/(^\S*) = (\S*)/mp;
if ( $str =~ /$regex/g ) {
print "$2";
}
```

The example.config:

```
[ORACLE]
ORACLE_BASE = /u01/oracle
ORACLE_HOME = $ORACLE_BASE/12.1.0.2
ORACLE_SID = asi1
[ORACLE]
[FTP]
FILE1 = $DUMPFILE.dmp
FILE2 = $DUMPFILE.dmp.gz
FILE3 = $DUMPFILE.md5
[FTP]
```

As you can see here, it should work: https://regex101.com/r/KlCyVE/9
[image]

Comment: Well, it is not clear why you have chosen such **regex**? What information do you try to _extract_ from config file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `example.config` contains spaces within the lines, so the perl script sees just the first word from each line in `$ARGV[0]`.

This should fix it:

```
use strict;
my $str = join(" ", @ARGV); #THIS
my $regex = qr/(^\S*) = (\S*)/mp;
if ( $str =~ /$regex/g ) {
print "$2";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The line below, from you code, reads the first *word* from the command line and stores it in `$str`. Your regex expects the complete line

```
my $str = $ARGV[0];
```

Change the shell script from this

```
RESULT=$(perl /mnt/c/LINUX_STUFF/regex.pl $line)
```

to this, i.e. quoting the line

```
RESULT=$(perl /mnt/c/LINUX_STUFF/regex.pl "$line")
```